# MEMORY_SPACE ALLOCATION I/O addressing materials

Tags: assembly, memory, mapping, nasm, computer-science

I want to use Assembly to get the peripherals going, so i can build a GPU Assembly language and a binary interpreter. That way people will be able to run machine language code in their PC, and create their own functions, by combining a command line interface with both machine language commands, opcodes, bios interrupts, assembly, graphics language, c and c++, then move onto my own php, sql, bootstrap, javascript, css and html programming languages, which can handle everything in the computer.

What i don't know is how the memory space is allocated automatically for example, peripherals have specific memory address automatically established for memory mapped I/o.

I'm trying to find material which would tell me the full list of i/o addressing memory address spaces and allocations so i can set up my own memory address allocation system, and don't want to override system built i/o addresses.
please guide me to the most comprehensive material for i/o addressing and memory mamping i/o addressing!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The exact memory addresses assigned to devices in your system varies depending on what hardware you have, so you aren't going to find a reference that will tell you. There are a variety of tools available to examine your hardware and determine what devices are present and what addresses are assigned to them.